# Android app runs on Marshmallow and above API versions, but doesn't run below it

Tags: android, xml

I am making one Android app. The app is working fine in android M and above, but my API's are not working in android below M

Here is my android manifest file. What is wrong with that?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              package="com.milestonestudioz.adaalo"
              android:versionCode="1"
              android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="19"
                android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Usually you declare your min/target sdk in the build gradle file. Could you please go into detail what exactly is not working, and what you'd expect it to be?

Comment: I'm getting responses from server in android M and above. But not getting any response from android below M.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include the relevant parts and help us help you

Comment: Okay thanks. But please help.

Comment: Simply set android:targetSdkVersion to 19 and rebuild/install your apk to retry, see any difference. By this way SDK will have your apk work with API19 level. Remember to check your gradle file too.

Post more details about error / log / situation if still failed.

Comment: Can you come in TeamViewer and check. I've tried too many thing but failed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the min SDK version in the Gradle file of your Android folder. When you give there the min Sdk, I think it should work. In case of any more clarification do ask...